# How do you reset index of Series in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

After using value_counts in Pandas
I want to reset the index
but the first column's name is replace with 'index'
and every columns' name got pushed to the right

```
df = df[df['type']=='food']['fruit'].value_counts()
df = df.reset_index()
df

  index  fruit
0 apple  120
1 grape  110
2 orange 30
```

maybe I can use df.columns to rename colums
but is there anyway to prevent 'index' replacing fist column's name?
this is what i want

```
  fruit  number
0 apple  120
1 grape  110
2 orange 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to rename the index and the `name` parameter of [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
(df[df['type']=='food']['fruit'].value_counts()
 .rename_axis('fruit')
 .reset_index(name='number'))
```

Other option, use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
(df[df['type']=='food']
 .groupby('fruit', as_index=False)
 .agg(number=('fruit', 'count'))
)
```

output:

```
    fruit  number
0   Apple       2
1  Banana       1
```

Used input:

```
   type   fruit
0  food   Apple
1  food   Apple
2  food  Banana
```

Comment: Thanks :) Why is groupby different with value_counts?

Comment: @JasmineC `value_counts` removes the index name, which is why we need to put it back. `groupby` maintains the name.